# Query runs fine in Sql Server, but SqlDataAdapter returns an (The multi-part identifier could not be bound) exception on it

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ado.net, sql-server-2012

`SqlDataAdapter` returns an exception

> The multi-part identifier "cl.ClientID" could not be bound.
>   The multi-part identifier "cl.ClientName" could not be bound.

while running query

**Code:**

```
        try
        {
            dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlComm,newConn);
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            dataAdapter.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
    StockSymbol, StockVolume 
FROM 
    Client AS cl
INNER JOIN 
    ClientPortfolio AS cp ON cl.ClientID = cp.ClientID AND cl.ClientName = 'xyz'
```

But the same query executes fine in SSMS.

Typical query result in SSMS:

```
BCSI    24
CENT    2
JRJC    4000
PAYX    100000
UNAM    50
WSBF    100
```

Database connection also works fine and am able to retrieve other data from the database into my winforms application

Comment: I **highly doubt** that this query you're showing is **exactly** what you're passing into your `sqlComm`. The query you show works just fine - it would work just fine in the `SqlDataAdapter`, too. Check your C# code - I'm pretty sure your SQL statement there is different (e.g. you might not have the `cl` alias on the `Client` table, or something like that)

Comment: Can you post the connection string you are using to create "newConn"